# Boost query performance and showing records in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, performance

I have a table called `Person` with roughly a million records. I would like to display each of them as a card on the index page, but I am having performance issues. The view is rendered very slowly and is causing significant lag.

I simply had `@persons = Person.all` but it didn't work since it just crashed my app. Now, I am using the `Person.find_in_batches` method, which now allows me to display all the records within the page. Not only it takes a long time to load up the records but when I try to click a few buttons on the page, it either freezes or lags heavily. I'm lost on how I can improve performance.

For the record, here is my following code:

Person controller:

```
  def index
    batch_size = 5000
    @people_in_batches = Person.find_in_batches(batch_size: batch_size)
  end
```

Index view:

```
  <% @people_in_batches.each do |batch|%>
    <% batch.each do |person| %>
      <div>
        <span><%= person.name %></span>
        <span><%= person.date_if_birth.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></span>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just curious why would you want to display a million records in a single page? People  use pagination to display like 15 items each page in general.

Comment: @eux, I actually didn't know how to go about displaying a huge amount of records on a single page. Still learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter how you query the million records, it still a **million** records.

What you should do is consider adding pagination on your page, so you would only needs to fetch records for the corresponding page. Just like Gmail.

So on the backend, you can use gem like https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari to help you with pagination.

Other than that, you should also consider adding filters on the page too, e.g. *Active* / *Not Active*, to reduce the number of records on page load.